# ` Symbol in Swedish Pro layout OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I can't find ` character in the Swedish Pro Keyboard Layout in OSX.  Writing questions and answers in StackOverflow and creating bash scripts became harder.

I have to copy it from the internet every time.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a work around for Stack, SU etc.

You can wrap text within `` by selecting text, and the pressing `CTRL + K`, when posting an answer or question, 

**Note. Not a windows shortcut**

Comment: I just found this out thanks but still I need the charcter for the bash scripts and writing in my ghost blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just switched my keyboard layout to Swedish Pro to try.

Surprisingly, I have the `` ` ``, and it's very simple - use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ the key to the left of <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I believe this is the same position as the key in the Swedish regular keyboard.

I added an image of the Keyboard Viewer with the Swedish Pro layout plus the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier, where you can see the character:

[image: Swedish Pro + Shift in Keyboard Viewer]

Comment: Yeah, it works. But it feels weird with the cursor change. Waiting for a character to add the symbol on top.